# Dask: Stalling Tasks?

Tags: python, dask, distributed-computing, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have a dask batch inferencing work load that's applying machine learning predictions against 500K rows of features. I'm using `dask-yarn` on an EMR instance on AWS. There seems to be some stragglers that are holding up Dask and I am not sure how to deal with them. For the `assign` task, it's been stuck at 99531/100000, and I've been waiting forever. There have been other times when I've used Dask and it sometimes gets "stuck" on bigger datasets.

Code Example:

```
def model_predict(row, model_config, bert_model, bert_tokenizer, xgb_model):

    input_doc = row.to_dict()
    try:
        return predict_one(model_config, bert_model, bert_tokenizer, xgb_model, input_doc)
    except:
        return {'error_code': 500}


all_features_df = dd.read_csv(file)
all_features_df = all_features_df.repartition(npartitions=100000).persist()
all_features_df['prediction_response'] = all_features_df.apply(
        model_predict,
        model_config=base_config,
        bert_model=bert,
        bert_tokenizer=tokenizer,
        xgb_model=xgb,
        axis=1, 
        meta=('prediction_response', 'object'))
all_features_df = all_features_df.persist()
all_features_df.repartition(partition_size="100MB").to_parquet(f's3://my_data/predictions/batch={batch}/',
                                                       engine='pyarrow',
                                                       schema='infer')
```

[image]

Comment: If this is reproducible, it would probably make for a good issue on dask.distributed. I've certainly had the same experience when the number of tasks gets into the >100k territory using dask-gateway on a kubernetes cluster. The trick is it often seems like a mess of network and I/O problems rather than a dask scheduler one. I wonder if the problem could be a failed read from the disk cache? I'm not sure if there's a timeout and retry setting that could be set somewhere for the disk cache...

Comment: Thanks for the insights @MichaelDelgado - I could try asking on the `dask.distributed` thread. I'm not sure how to set a timeout or retry setting for the disk cache.

Comment: Noting the corresponding issue on dask/distributed: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/5879 -- Thanks for opening this, Riley!